# Layout inflating: only first view edited and not wrapping contents

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, layout-inflater

I'm trying to fill up a LinearLayout with some custom items, creating a view dynamically every time and inflating it into my Linear.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mLinearLayoutList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

The problem is that my List is filled, but only the first item is correctly shown with the visibility and informations I put.

This is the code I use to inflate my views.

```
        mLinearLayoutList.removeAllViews();
        for (InterventionActivityFieldAdapterPojo interventionActivityFieldAdapterPojo :
                myNonRealmActivitieAdapterPojos) {
            View myRow = null;
            switch (interventionActivityFieldAdapterPojo.getType()) {
                case TITOLO:
                    myRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_interventionactivity_title, mLinearLayoutList, true);
                    break;
                case FIGLIO:
                    myRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_interventionactivity_son, mLinearLayoutList, true);
                    break;
                case PADRE:
                    myRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_interventionactivity, mLinearLayoutList, true);
                    break;
            }
           //here I initialize the row with my helper class. I find views and I set up everything
           [...]
```

And I have an helper class that I use to initialize every row, but since it's too long I can't post it here. It only picks up Views (textviews, buttons, ...) and it set visibilities and values.

I debugged and I have no errors, the helper class run correctly and the linearLayout is filled.

The problems are mainly 2:

- Only the first row is set, the other ones are "basics" as it is in the xml.
- The linearlayout is not wrapping rows, it is only "match parent" in the view.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you tried to make a listview with an adapter and do your switch case into the getView of the adapter? That look better for what you need to do.

Comment: check for layout orientation .Vertical

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi i forgot the xml, added. it is already vertical unfortunatly

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley kindly add Screen shot of layout.!

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi it has many stuffs, the main concept is indipendent from the layout and it is that the inflated views are not istantiated, but "default"